# Simple way to run two while loops at the same time using threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked through all the previous answers, and they are all too complicated for a beginner like me. I want to run too while loops at the same time. For example, I want to run these two at the same time:

```
def firstFunction():
    do things

def secondFunction():
    do some other things
```

As I said, the other answers are too complex for me to understand.

Comment: *Why* are they too complex? What did you try to do that didn't work?

Comment: What do the two loops do? When and how do the functions stop? What happens if one stops before the other?

Comment: Where are the while loops you're referring to?  Are they inside the functions?

Comment: This (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) is a primer that I found pretty helpful, my advice is that you should read and understand that first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your while loops are within the functions you listed, this is the easiest way I can think of.

```
from threading import Thread

t1 = Thread(target = firstFunction)
t2 = Thread(target = secondFunction)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

As pointed out by tdelaney, doing it this way will just kick off each thread and immediately move on.  If you need to wait for those threads to complete before running the rest of your program you can use the .join() method.

Comment: `t1.join()` and `t2.join()` are needed so that the app waits for the threads to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty basic thread class that can get you up and running.

```
from threading import *

class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self._target()
```

To call it use:

```
ThreadOne = FuncThread(firstFunction())
ThreadOne.start()
secondFunction()
ThreadOne.join()
```

That should get you pretty close.  You're gonna have to play with it to make it work in your scenario.  Be careful running those multiple `while` loops, make sure you build in an exit.  Threading is tough but try and read up on it in the documentation and make what I've provided work for you if you can.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: FuncThread doesn't add anything beyond what threading.Thread does anyway. No need to complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `thread` module:

```
import thread
def firstFunction():
    while some_condition:
       do_something()

def secondFunction():
    while some_other_condition:
       do_something_else()

thread.start_new_thread(firstFunction, ())
thread.start_new_thread(secondFunction, ())
```

Comment: What about those functions are infinite loop?

Comment: @OfirAttia They will still run, but will never end. You probably want a handle on the thread to end it later on, so then use (in Python 2.7) the `threading.Thread` class.