# Make two while loops one loop

Tags: python, loops

I have two while loops that are almost identical apart from a few numbers have changed. I've been looking around but I can't find a solution to my problem. Any help would be appreciated. I want to make the two while loops one loop but I dont know how. I've been looking around for an answer but nothing seems to apply to my problem.

```
while True:
    print("User 1")
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    loggedin=False
    if login.lower()=="yes":
        login1=open("login.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(login1)
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username1:
                if row[1]==password1:
                    print("Welcome " + username1)
                    loggedin=True
                    break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
            continue

    elif login.lower()=="no":
        print(" ")
        print("Make an account.")
        print(" ")
        username1=input("What is your username: ")
        password1=input("What is your password: ")
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        continue
```

The only thing that has changed is the number 1 has changed to a number 2 (with the exception of row[1])
Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean to say, two loops? there is only one while loop in the code

Comment: What about using an outside `for` loop?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the OP wants to write another almost identical `while` loop (except for the user number, ...) and does not know how to do...am I right?

Comment: Please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Comment: OP's code is not indented well.Also `while` loop indents, its going forever.
@toti08 , question title says otherwise

Comment: @angrysumit, yeah, I was just trying to guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you saying the only difference is 1 becomes 2 I'm guessing you are just trying to run the loop again for a second user, perhaps a dictionary here, then you could just iterate the loop you already have constructed for each user in the dicitonary, you would have to touch up your loops I cannot run them but an idea for format would be something like so

```
while True:
    users = {'User 1': [username1, password1], 'User 2': [username2, password2]}
    for k in users:
        print('{}'.format(k))
        login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
        loggedin=False
        if login.lower()=="yes":
            login1=open("login.csv")
            reader = csv.reader(login1)
            users[k][0]=input("What is your username: ")
            users[k][1]=input("What is your password: ")
            for row in reader:
                if row[0]==users[k][0]:
                    if row[1]==users[k][1]:
                        print("Welcome " + users[k][0])
                        loggedin=True
                        break
            if loggedin==False:
                print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
                continue

        elif login.lower()=="no":
            print(" ")
            print("Make an account.")
            print(" ")
            users[k][0]=input("What is your username: ")
            users[k][1]=input("What is your password: ")
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
            continue
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your while loops are within the functions you listed, this is the easiest way I can think of.

```
from threading import Thread
    t1 = Thread(target = firstFunction)
    t2 = Thread(target = secondFunction)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: For further information, you could negative to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773474/simple-way-to-run-two-while-loops-at-the-same-time-using-threading